# Returning results based on group of statuses records in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return records based on whether clients meet the following criteria:

> Record1 Statuses:     New, Completed, Completed, Cancelled,
>
> Record2 Statuses:     Completed, Completed, Cancelled
>
> Record3 Statuses:     Completed Cancelled Cancelled
>
> Record4 Statuses:     New, Completed, Cancelled, Cancelled

My query needs to return ALL the records that don't have "New" statuses. e.g. Record2 and Record3 BUT not Record1 and Record4 (since they have "New") for each client.

Comment: Can you post your table structure and clean up your sample data?  The answer to this will change depending on whether all your statuses are in a single field, a single row, or multiple rows ... see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question probably needed an [mcve] at the time, and appears now to be abandoned. I am recommending it be put on hold for now, until it is edited to include the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a lot of assumptions writing the following query since you didn't provide table structure but I guess it should go something like this.

```
 select *
 from RecordTable
 where status not in ('new')
```

Now if the column is a comma delimited column I guess you will probably want something like this

```
 select *
 from RecordTable
 where CHARINDEX('new',status)=0
```